# How can I freeze excess peas from my garden?

Tags: freezing

Would you recommend blanching them first or freezing them raw?

Answer (score 6):

According to the Ball Blue Book of Canning & Freezing:

> Scalding is a critical step in preparing vegetables for freezing and must be done carefully.  (This is a "must" for all vegetables to be stored frozen for more than four weeks, except those used exlusively for their flavor such as green onions, hot peppers and herbs.) Scalding cleanses the surface of dirt and organisms, brightens the color, helps retain vitamins and reduces the action of enzymes which would otherwise destroy the fresh flavor after about four weeks.  It also shrinks the product, making packing easier.

The recommended scalding time for fresh green peas is 2 minutes.  Be sure to have your ice bath prepared for shocking them before starting the scalding to avoid overcooking them.
Once shocked, remove from the ice bath to avoid leaching nutrients, flavor, and color.

Comment: I agree but would add that when you freeze them, spread thrum evenly on a cookie sheet lined with wax paper. They will freeze individually and not stuck together. Once frozen you can transfer to a freezer bag.

Comment: Provided that they're not wet the waxy skin prevents them from sticking together.  Haven't had any issues but you can also do them individually first.  Individually is most important for soft fleshed items such as berries.

Comment: If you don't have a canning book and are looking for instructions, The National Center for Home Food Preservation (http://www.uga.edu/nchfp/) is the best resource on the web.